# GeoWebCache returns files as geoserver-dispatch.application instead of kml in Chrome

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

This url: http://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/geoserver/gwc/service/kml/GCC_cuo:GCC_Image.png.kml should download a kml file, but it doesn't in Chrome. It downloads a geoserver-dispatch.application file instead.

It does download fine in IE.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade GeoServer to the latest version (2.4-RC1), the file name should have been fixed there

Comment: I'm still seeing this on 2.6.2